# ASP WebService high latency

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am writing a `WebService` in .NET Framework 4.7.2. I am experiencing high latency on my requests. When I call a WebMethod using PostMan, it takes almost 2 seconds to even hit the constructor in my web service class. What would cause such high latency? I'm using Debug using IIS Express from Visual studio 2019. I have also tried Release Mode, and also "Run Without Debugging". Everything seems to take at least 2000ms latency for a seemingly simple request. This happens on every request (not just the first request).

```
public class MyService: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        public MyService()
        {
            // Takes almost 2000ms to get to this point
        }
}
```

The rest of my code (constructor/`WebMethod`) executes almost instantaneously once it finally gets to my constructor. Why is there so much overhead/latency before it gets to my code? Is this due to IIS Express? Would it be faster using a full version of IIS?

I come from background of ASP.NET Core, so I'm not to familiar with the inner workings of old/legacy ASP stuff. What sort of things should I be looking for to help with the request latency?

Comment: check on `global.asax` nd the `Application_BeginRequest` to see if you run there anything...

Comment: If this is a WCF app, try enabling logs and see how long does the service take to instantiate your request